# Difference between 决策 and 决定

Tags: difference

I'm trying to understand the difference between 决策 and 决定. It seems like 决策 is used more formally and in the case of business contexts more (e.g. 战略决策 - strategic decision)。 But, I wasn't sure if that was entirely rue.

For example, could I say 在京东所有重要的决策由刘强东拍板

or should I say 决定？

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your first example is right, it can't be replaced with 决定.

Answer (score 1):

决策is a noun and can only be used as a noun
for example 这是一个非常重要的决策。this is a very important decision.
决定 is a verb but also a noun
verb example 你要决定你想去哪。you need to decide where you want to go
noun example 这是老板的决定，不是我的。this is the boss's decision, not mine.
hope this helps.
P.S. I am Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

decide --- 决定(verb)

decision --- 决定(noun)

policy decision --- 决策

decision making --- 决策

decision theory --- 决策论

Answer (score 1):

决策 is mostly used as noun and Predicate, while 决定 can be used both as noun and verb.

**决策 as Predicate in Idioms:**

when uses as Predicate it's short for 决定策略, which means decide the policies and strategies to apply

运筹决策(make decision through operations research)

决策千里(make strategic decision from thousand miles away)

**决策 as noun:**

重大决策(big and important decision)

**决定 as noun**

我做了个正确的决定(I made a right decision)

**决定 as verb**

我决定学习汉语(I decided to learn Chinese)

when use as noun they have very similar meaning, only 决策 stresses that the decision is calculated and important. while 决定 is neutral.

by the way, **策** means compiled Bamboo slip(竹简) you can google photos for it. In ancient times our ancestors wrote on 竹简. important things are recorded on 竹简. so 竹简 becomes the symbol of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what authority (or veto power maybe) that 刘强东 has. Also it sounds redundant to say 重要的决策, can you think of any 不重要的决策？

If I were to say it, it's either 
在京东所有的决策由刘强东拍板
or
在京东所有重要的决定由刘强东拍板

For example, could I say 在京东所有重要的决策由刘强东拍板

Answer (score -1):

決策 is strategy, a noun.

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000097229

決定 is "to determine", roughly used as a verb:

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000097201

by the way, 决 (u+51b3) is, well, not ...
it should be 決 (u+6c7a), have a look of this page:

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=決](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%B1%BA)

it states clearly: 決﹒行流也﹒从水从夬

三點﹒部首「水」也﹒兩點﹒部首「冫」也, get it :)

Comment: for  决定 used as noun see iciba：decision，in today＇s news：日本外相岸田文雄在日中外长会谈中，向中国外长王毅转达了日本政府的这一决定。

Comment: 决 is the simplified character for 決, with a long long history dating back to Han Dynasty.

Comment: i knew it.
well, 决 is not in the 國語辭典, nor 漢語多功能字庫; then 說文解字 stated clearly 从水从夬. 从水, the radical should be 氵(U+6c35).

Comment: one more source: 教育部異體字字典 (from taiwan, in traditional chinese)


http://dict2.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAyMTQ1LTAwMQ

Answer (score -1):

决策更倾向于一个“策略”（策）
决定更强调一个“结果”（定）
决定不光可以做动词也可以做名词
决策一般用作名词